# How to insert new element after EVERY tag with class name?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

After every `<div class="myclass"></div>` I want to insert `<p>abc</p>`.

**My code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="myclass">
    <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <p>Some other content.</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

new_element = soup.new_tag('p')
new_element.string = 'abc'

for div in soup.find_all('div', 'myclass'):
    div.insert_after(new_element)

print(soup)
```

**My output**

```
<div class="myclass">
<p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
<p>Some other content.</p>
</div><p>abc</p>
```

My code only inserts the new element after the last appearance of `myclass`. What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the tag each time:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = '''
<div class="myclass">
    <p>Some content.</p>
</div>
<div class="myclass">
    <p>Some other content.</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', 'myclass'):
    new_element = soup.new_tag('p')
    new_element.string = 'abc'
    div.insert_after(new_element)

print(soup)
```

This gave me:

```
<div class="myclass">
<p>Some content.</p>
</div><p>abc</p>
<div class="myclass">
<p>Some other content.</p>
</div><p>abc</p>
```

Comment: So after one use the variable will be deleted? Crazy.

Comment: @Sr.Schneider nothing's deleted... it's just that you have a *single* instance of that `p` tag and that single object can only exist in *one* place in the tree... so you create the object, then insert it after the first `div` (if you put a break in your original loop - you'll see it's after your first `div`), then you insert after the *same* object after the second div... (you're basically moving that single `p` tag in the tree...)

Comment: @Sr.Schneider for instance - after the code above, try a `div.insert_before(new_element)` and see what happens when you `print(soup)` again